# Laravel 5.6 update record from form in a model not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple crud system that I build everything works fine except the UPDATE part.

When you try to edit a record a bootstrap modal pops up with a form in it with the records populated done with javascript. The action url for the form is also set by javascript. When I submit, the model simply closes, nothing happens.

Let's start with my resource route:

```
Route::resource('buildingimage', 'BuildingImageController');
```

The edit button:

```
<button
    class="edit-modal btn btn-info"
    data-buildingid="{{$building->id}}"
    data-location="{{$building->location}}"
    data-source="{{$building->source}}"
    data-disc="{{$building->disc}}"
    data-result="{{$building->result}}"
    data-resultPositive="{{$building->result_info_positive}}"
    data-resultNegative="{{$building->result_info_negative}}"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#edit-building"
>
    <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
    Edit
</button>
```

I use all these data attributes to populate the edit form via javascript:

```
$('#edit-building').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            let editUrl = 'buildingimage/' + $(e.relatedTarget).data('buildingid');
            $('#editBuilding').attr('action', editUrl);

            let location = $(e.relatedTarget).data('location');
            let source = $(e.relatedTarget).data('source');
            let disc = $(e.relatedTarget).data('disc');
            let result = $(e.relatedTarget).data('result');
            let resultPostitive =  $(e.relatedTarget).data('resultPostive');
            let resultNegative = $(e.relatedTarget).data('resultNegative');

            $('input[name=location]').val(location);
            $('input[name=source]').val(source);
            $('select[name=disc]').val(disc);
            $('select[name=result]').val(result);
    });
```

The form in my modal:

```
{{ Form::open(['id' => 'editBuilding', 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        {{ Form::label('location', Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.location')) }}
                        {{ Form::text('location', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 noPaddingLeft">
                        {{ Form::label('source', Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.source')) }}

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 noPaddingLeft">
                        {{ Form::label('disc', Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.disc')) }}
                        {{ Form::select('disc', ['0' => Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.notdisc'), '1' => Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.disc')], null, ['id' => 'discDropdown', 'class' => 'form-control'])}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 noPaddingLeft">
                        {{ Form::label('result', Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.result')) }}
                        {{ Form::select('result', ['positive' => Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.positive'), 'negative' => Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.negative')], null, ['id' => 'resultDropdown', 'class' => 'form-control'])}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 noPaddingLeft">
                        <div id="resultPositive">
                            {{ Form::label('resultpostitive', Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.resultpositive')) }}
                            {{ Form::select('result_info_positive', ['positive' => Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.positive'), 'negative' => Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.negative')], null, ['id' => 'resultPositiveDropdown', 'class' => 'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                        <div id="resultNegative">
                            {{ Form::label('resultnegative', Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.resultnegative')) }}
                            {{ Form::select('result_info_negative', ['positive' => Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.positive'), 'negative' => Lang::get('image_request.execute.building.negative')], null, ['id' => 'resultNegativeDropdown', 'class' => 'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 noPaddingLeft">
                        <br>
                        {!! Form::hidden('image_request_id', $imageRequest->id) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Now I have no idea why the form is not submitting, literally nothing happens the modal just closes.

### EDIT submit button in modal

I forgot to show how I submit my form in the modal:

```
<button type="submit" form="editBuilding" class="btn btn-primary edit" data-dismiss="modal">
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-check'></span> @lang('image_request.execute.building.edit_modal.confirm')
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method type on your form to `POST` and put

```
@method('PUT')
```

within your form.

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing) is the reason for that

Also in your JS, you need to prevent the default behavior of the modal. To do that, you can either put as a first line in the script.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

or `return false;` at the end.

And then in the bottom of the script you will need to submit the form, after you've modified it.

```
$('#editBuilding').submit();
```

Comment: I've actualy tried this as my initial code but it's the same, nothing happens the modal simply closes

Comment: I don't see your route in the form?
`Form::open(['route'  => ['buildingimage.update'], 'id' => 'editBuilding', 'method' => 'PUT'])`

Comment: I can't give my route like that since I need to give it an id I set the action/route attribute via javascript, look at my javascript I posted in OP

Comment: ah, it is misleading, you call it `deleteUrl` when it is `edit` so that confused me.

Comment: Yeah you're right that's a very bad name lol, I'll edit OP and my code

Comment: Where do I put the e.preventDefault()? Look at my JS it is a function to show the modal if i put it there the modal wont show

Comment: I edited OP with how I submit the edit form I forgot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183544/discussion-between-nakov-and-michael).